# treelib prints garbage instead of pseudographics in Python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode

I created tree in [treelib](http://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and called

```
tree.show()
```

Ufortunately instead of tree it prints something like

```
b'Hips\n\xe2\x94\x9c\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 LeftUpLeg\n\xe2\x94\x82   \xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 LeftLeg\n\xe2\x94\x82
```

I saw such b-prefixed strings many time but don't know what do they mean. Something like incompatibility between Python 2 and 3?

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug, partly addressed.

See [this issue raised on github](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib/issues/221).

In your Python installation, go to `Lib\site-packages\treelib` and look at `tree.py`. **Since 1.7.0**, in `def show`, the last lines are:

```
if stdout:
    print(self._reader.encode("utf-8"))
else:
    return self._reader
```

The problem is in this line, which doesn't respect the console's default encoding:

```
print(self._reader.encode('utf-8'))
```

Instead you want to print the reader itself, which you can get by calling `tree.show(stdout=False)` from your application (no need to edit the library source):

```
. . .
print(tree.show(stdout=False))
```

Printing Unicode strings directly should encode them in the console's default encoding, so as long as your console supports the line drawing characters, it will print fine.

If you have an earlier version of treelib, you can edit the library `tree.py` file and change the last line to be:

```
print(self.reader)
```

This works like:

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from treelib import Tree
>>> tree=Tree()
>>> tree.create_node('A','a')
Node(tag='A', identifier='a', data=None)
>>> tree.create_node('B','b',parent='a')
Node(tag='B', identifier='b', data=None)
>>> tree.show()
A
└── B
```

It's probably not the only bug.  The author isn't following the rule of encoding/decoding at the I/O boundaries of a program and work with Unicode internally.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 we would expect `show` to print a string.  Instead it seems to be printing an object in the `bytes` type: a sequence of bytes which is actually a string encoded in a particular character encoding.

In this example, the encoding is `utf-8`.  We can see this using code like this:

```
import codecs

x = b'Hips\n\xe2\x94\x9c\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 LeftUpLeg\n\xe2\x94\x82   \xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 LeftLeg\n\xe2\x94\x82 '
s = codecs.decode(x,"utf-8")
print(s)
```

which prints the correct tree.

This must be a bug in the treelib code.  In fact, looking at the code we can see the following line:

```
print(self.reader.encode('utf-8'))
```

This is wrong.  Raise an issue with the treelib developers.  In the meantime if you replace with:

```
print(self.reader)
```

this will work.

Comment: It doesn't return it, it prints it. Return value is `None` :)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR the other answers are getting stale... since [1.7.0](https://pypi.org/project/treelib/1.7.0/) the library has `tree.show(stdout=False)` to workaround this issue.  Make this change to your code:

```
-     tree.show()
+     print(tree.show(stdout=False))
```